# How to access super function when overriding a function using a function passed as a parameter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, parameters, parent, super, higher-order-functions

I am overriding the functions of different classes by passing an object of functions as a parameter.

`var parameter = {function1: function() {...}, function2: function() {...}}`

Is it possible to call the original function, as would be done using super() when extending the class, from the overriding function being passed in?

`var parameter = {function1: function() {// I want to call the original function1 of whatever class im going to be overriding, then do something else}, function2: function() {...}}`

Further context: I am making a custom widget on surveyjs.

Comment: Its not possible.